# What is the meaning of the term 'jazz-hands'?

Tags: meaning

The book "Greetings From Witness Protection" has the following sentence:
"I never saw an adult make jazz-hands before."

What in the world does that mean?

Comment: ["jazz hands"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jazz+hands%22&oq=%22jazz+hands%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5725j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the selection [Greetings from Witness Protection](https://books.google.com/books?id=YBlVDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA39&dq=%22jazz-hands%20%22%20in%20witness%20protection&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q=%22jazz-hands%20%22%20in%20witness%20protection&f=false) and it shed no light on the meaning.

**jazz hands**  [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/jazz-hands)

> in dance, musicals, cabaret, etc., the action of waving the hands with
>   the palms facing forward and the fingers wide open, in order to show
>   excitement or enthusiasm

The exact origins of [jazz hands](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/the-fabulous-history-of-jazz-hands)

> are a bit murky, but as with most performative dance, it likely has
>   its roots in African dance traditions. “I see one thread of it coming
>   up through the African-American foundation of jazz dance, and that
>   authentic jazz tradition.

and

> Some people contend that jazz hands can be traced back to Al Jolson’s
>   1927 film, The Jazz Singer.

My sense is it demonstrates excitement and or approval.

[image: jazz hands]